# SVG constructive area geometry?

Tags: java, svg, geometry

Are there SVG functions that perform CAG operations similar to those that `Area` provides in Java (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html)?

I would like to perform those operations directly using an SVG library (e.g. Batik), not through the Batik Graphics2D class that does SVG export (since I would rather use the SVG API than Java2D).

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

SVG doesn't have any functions built into them, its mearly a graphics drawing spec..(with the exception of some animation functionality)

I would preprocess the vector values your app is using and then apply them to the rendering of the SVG.

Without knowing your platform, or your application of the SVG...its hard to help any further.  SVG can be used in a lot of ways and places! :)

The references to Java allow me to assume that your using it as your interface engine? but thats about it..if you want to know the area of the circle, you would have to find the circle in the DOM tree, extrude the attributes from the the node, and just push them into a standard CAG class to do the math for you.